# sqlite database cursor

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I want store user data in database using sqlite. How do i make a cursor in sqlite and use it to navigate to the end of a database in sqlite? 
Something similar to this:(python)

```
import sqlite3;
from datetime import datetime, date;

conn = sqlite3.connect('banklist.sqlite3')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('drop table if exists failed_banks')
c.execute('create table failed_banks(id integer primary key autoincrement, 
name text, city text, state text, zip integer, close_date text, updated_date text)')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for not directly answering your question, but have you considered taking a look at the Core Data Programming Guide. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

You can design your database visually and use auto-generated code for access to your data. It saves a lot of time and effort and does not require you to write lines of SQL.